# Swagger2 springboot springfox cannot rename api

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

I tried to use @Api and @ApiModel to rename my api reference but nothing seems to work. It always takes the class name. Im using swagger2 + springfox 2.4 + springboot.

Comment: Please paste your code so that we can better understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Actually i was able to rename my Api's using the tags property inside @Api

```
@Api(tags='NiceName')
public class myapi {...}
```